# Adobe Flash Player causes my computer to crash

Tags: windows-7, adobe-flash

Occasionally when I'm using Flash Player,  my computer completely freezes up, my screen turns to a whole bunch of lines, and the sound that was playing, repeats itself, (only the last few milliseconds), the HDD also shuts off / is disconnected.
Needless to say, keyboard and mouse also are not at all functional.

There is no one particular site that I have this problem with.  Its all of them, yet its only occasionally IE. once a night.

I recognize that I may not be describing my problem exactly right, yet I'm sure I'll be prodded for more detailed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your video driver to the latest version from [Nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) or [AMD/ATI](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) depending on which you have in your computer.

Comment: Already done.  doesn't help.  Why do you think its a video driver issue?

Comment: System lockups often are caused by misbehaved drivers, and video drivers often are the culprit since they're so complex.  You might also check audio drivers to be sure they're up to date.  If this is a computer you built yourself, check the motherboard manufacturer's website for updated drivers.

Comment: didn't help.  What else can I do?

Comment: A few other things to try: Update the motherboard BIOS to the latest version.  Look inside the case and make sure every connector is securely fastened and every add-on card such as the graphics card is secure in its slot.  You also might try installing Speedfan (http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) or some other temperature monitoring utility and watch the CPU temperature to see if the CPU is overheating.

Comment: I am using a laptop so looking at it may be a little difficult.  I do use "CORE TEMP" to monitor heat, and heat has no relation to when/if the computer freezes up.

Comment: One more thing to try is to install Google Chrome and run your Flash in Chrome.  It has its own built-in version of Flash Player.  If you're already using Chrome, try IE or Firefox which will use the version of Flash Player you installed separately.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your video card it may be the latest driver causing the freeze up. Try going back to an older driver package of video card. As gordoco mentioned the video card drivers are very complex. I had a very similar on my laptop. After watching some videos (where I watched them was unimportant)  my system would freeze up and make that awful sound. I uninstalled the latest driver package to my video card and went to the version before and no freezing as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have tried uninstalling and re-installing it, but use the [Flash Uninstaller](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html) and follow the directions in the link.

Then reinstall it and give it a shot.

Comment: How is Flash Uninstaller different than the normal uninstaller (through add and remove programs)?

Comment: If is it like most special uninstallers, it hunts more deeply for possible registry changes, and other components that a regular installer might leave behind. In a perfect world, you are right, they SHOULD be the same, but in practice, most programs leave a lot behind when uninstalled the normal way.

Comment: Didn't help.  Still have the problem